# iOS maps show the center of a specific city

Tags: ios, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I am using MapKit and CoreLocation to find the users location and then display it on a map.

I am using this code to display the City and State (which is what I am interested in, not the EXACT location).

```
// this delegate is called when the app successfully finds your current location
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:self.locationManager.location
                   completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                       NSLog(@"reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler: Completion Handler called!");

                       if (error){
                           NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
                           return;

                       }


                       CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

                       CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;

                       zoomLocation.latitude = placemark.region.center.latitude;
                       zoomLocation.longitude= placemark.region.center.longitude;

                       MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, METERS_PER_MILE * 2, METERS_PER_MILE * 2);

                       [self.mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:NO];


                       NSString *location = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", placemark.locality, placemark.administrativeArea];

                       NSLog(@"%@", location);

                   }];

}
```

This works great, but what I really want to do is zoom in to the center of the city itself, not the users location.

Is there some kind of property I can access to do this?

Otherwise, is anyone aware of a work around? That would be great, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by the "center of the city"?

Comment: When visiting maps.google.com, type in a city and state only. The map will drop a pin in what appears to be the center of the city on the map and zoom in to this point. Apple maps works a little different when performing the same task. I do not want to use the Google Maps API (which I have not checked to see if it can do this easily either) to display the map, I just need to find coordinates that are near the center a city selected by the user.

Answer (score 5):

not directly. There is **no** api like `MKGetClosestCapitalTo(userLocation)`

BUT

you can use the user's location for reverse geocoding and THEN use the city name to geocode  the address => that will get you the city center.

so:

1. address = reversegeocode(userLocation)
2. loc = geocode(address.cityName)
3. zoom map to that loc

(you already have 1 so just do 2 and 3 ;))

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Daij-Djan's approach of doing two geocodes to essentially "lose resolution" in the query. For example, if you find that the user is at a certain address in Austin, TX, then you would get just "Austin, TX" out of the results and ask for the coordinate of *that*. Then you will have the center of what Apple considers Austin.

Another approach might be to tie into an external database or API. For example, Wikipedia has a center coordinate for each city it contains that you might be able to query & use.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to center around particular city, you can specify the coordinate of the city in following code and the map view will be centred around it.

```
 MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance("SPECIFY THE COORDINATE OF THE CITY YOU WANT TO CENTER AROUND HERE", 800, 800);
[self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
```

Comment: This is correct, which as you can see in my code, I am currently doing. This will only work if I already have the coordinated of all cities and can cross reference what the CLLocationManager finds, or the string the user types into a text field.

Comment: But you are centring around user location, not around any city.